# HOW to merge table cells with python-pptx lib

Tags: python, python-pptx

I have been faced with problem: How to merge some cells into big cell (vertically or horizontally merging) with python-pptx library?

I've found no examples to do this and I need some help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** Cell Merge was added to `python-pptx` in version 0.6.14. The method is documented here:
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/table.html#docx.table._Cell.merge

Basically, you define a rectangular region to merge by specifying two diagonal corner cells, so something like this:

```
table.cell(0, 0).merge(table.cell(1, 1))
```

would merge the top-left four cells, two in each of the first two rows.

---

Unfortunately, this feature has not yet been implemented in `python-pptx`.

To accomplish this, you would need to extend `python-pptx` with some sort of workaround function.

These issues from the GitHub project may provide some useful information if you want to pursue that:
https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+merge+label%3Atable

Comment: Hi scanny, it seems now python-pptx has already achieved the ability of merging cells?

Comment: Yes, it was, I've updated the response to reflect that, thanks @ShiangHoo :)

Comment: Thanks, great job! I'm enjoying it~